# python-telegram-bot хендлер для списка

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

как с помощью python-telegram-bot можно написать один хендлер для списка данных?
Вот пример того что я хочу сделать, но второй хендлер так не работает он принимает str, не могу найти информацию с реализацией такой задачи.

```
def set_handlers(dp: Updater.dispatcher) -> None:
    """Регистрируем здесь все хендлеры."""
    dp.add_handler(InlineQueryHandler(get_categories, pattern='categories'))
    dp.add_handler(InlineQueryHandler(get_concrete, pattern=['open', 'closed']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Б документаций написано
pattern

Optional. Regex pattern to test telegram.InlineQuery.query against.

Type str | Pattern

У вас Type list

Comment: Да, я знаю что я передаю type list, я спрашивал как возможно реализовать хендлер для list?